# pd.dataframe: subsetting df to a minimum amount of features in a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to create a pivot table in pandas that should only show features in a grouped column if the features have a minimum number. Eg: When I group features in column Level_1, it should only included features that have a minimum of 3 appearances in column "Level_2", so I don´t have any grouped features with only 1 or 2 appearances. I want to use this df for a plot sunburst chart and such small numbers make the chart impossible to read.

I have created the following line of code, that only creates a boolean mask, it seems, but not the reduced dataframe I am looking for.

```
df_new = df.groupby('Level_1').agg({'Level_2': 'count'}) > 2
```

What generates a useless df full of NaNs is:

```
df_new = df[df.groupby('Level_1').agg({'Level_2': 'count'}) > 2]
```

What is needed to filter the df to leave only Level_1 features with a quantity of at least 3 each?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead. In the future, please attach an example df, and a resulting df that you are trying to get to.

```
df_new = df.loc[df.groupby('Level_1')['Level_2'].transform('count').gt(2)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, that actually helped.